# C# Linq GroupBy and Select performance

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working with a third part service of my client that is providing me a list of products and services, which is a little bit of a mess.

The list will return all of the `services` for the `product` but the `product` `repeats itself`, for example:

The **product A** has the **service A** and the **product A** also has the **service B** so, when i receive the list i will get **two products A** with **services A and B**

What i need to do is to group all of the products to get only one with all of it's services and i have done so but i'm worried about performance because i think my solution isn't the 'best' one:

```
var productsNormalized = products.Data.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new ProdutoSSO
{
    CodigoServico = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["CodigoServico"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["CodigoServico"].ToString()),
    CodigoPeca = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["CodigoPeca"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["CodigoPeca"].ToString()),
    CodigoFamilia = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["CodigoFamilia"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["CodigoFamilia"].ToString()),
    Familia = x["Familia"].ToString(),
    Servico = x["Servico"].ToString(),
    Peca = x["Peca"].ToString(),
    Hash = x["Hash"].ToString(),
    Valor = decimal.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["Valor"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["Valor"].ToString())
})
.GroupBy(x => new { x.CodigoPeca, x.CodigoFamilia, x.Familia, x.Peca })
.Select(x => new ProdutoGroup
{
    Produto = new Produto
    {
        CodigoPeca = x.Key.CodigoPeca,
        CodigoFamilia = x.Key.CodigoFamilia,
        Familia = x.Key.Familia,
        Peca = x.Key.Peca
    },
    Servicos = x.Select(y => new ProdutoServico
    {
        CodigoServico = y.CodigoServico,
        Hash = y.Hash,
        Servico = y.Servico,
        Valor = y.Valor
    }).ToList()
});
```

Is there a better way to achieve this or this is as good as it gets?

Comment: How long is the code taking? How long do you want it to take?

Comment: *' to get only one with all of it's services '* - seems like you are taking all groups and all services in you query. There is no filtering and nothing like `Take(1)` or `First()`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy the problem is the service, it will returna a list of all products, no filter, no nothing. I have to do this on my side

Comment: @mjwills I don't really have any numbers since we are still on dev stage and i don't have the full database, only parcial. On my machine it takes less than 5 seconds. My concern is because it will be used heavily and i can't have any cache options because of the prices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s a review of an existing code and should therefor go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not sure that it will help but you can try to remove the first projection (select) as it does not make much of a difference anyway. Get directly to your grouping stage and take some statistics.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly, then this might be a good case to use [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) rather than `GroupBy` with a `Select` (with an inner `Select`). You could aggregate to a `Dictionary` of `ProdutoGroup` building up the `Servicos` as you go. That would probably avoid a few iterations through the whole list.

Comment: @MattBurland I don't see how that is going to work because i really need to group them before i can create the new lists. Could you please provide an example of what u meant ? I tried to implement but i think i ain't seeing what u saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Aggregate you could do something like this (assuming you are starting with a list of `ProdutoSSO`, which might not be entirely necessary):

```
var productsNormalized = productoSSOs
    .Aggregate(new Dictionary<Produto,List<ProdutoServico>>(ProductoComparer),
    (p,c) => {
    var product = new Produto
    {
        CodigoPeca = c.CodigoPeca,
        CodigoFamilia = c.CodigoFamilia,
        Familia = c.Familia,
        Peca = c.Peca
    };
    var service = new ProdutoServico
    {
        CodigoServico = c.CodigoServico,
        Hash = c.Hash,
        Servico = c.Servico,
        Valor = c.Valor
    };
    if (!p.ContainsKey(product)) 
    {
        p[product] = new List<ProductoServico>() { service };
    } 
    else
    {
        p[product].Add(service);
    }
    return p;
});
```

Where `ProductoComparer` is an `IEqualityComparer<Producto>` (or alternatively you could implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Producto`, or you could just generate a key some other way - concatenating fields together, for example).

This is obviously untested since I don't have the original classes or data.

This would give you a `Dictionary<Producto, List<ProductoServico>>` which might be all you need, or you can easily transform it into an `IEnumerable<ProdutoGroup>` if you want.

Comment: It's giving me an error: `The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(IEnumerable<TSource>, TAccumulate, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

Comment: Sorry, I *always* forget the `return` when using `Aggregate`. Try it now.

Comment: I had already added the return p. It still shows me the same message, it looks like it can't define the types. I tried to add them at `Aggregate<>` but i couldn't find the correct match.

Comment: Sorry, I had the seed and the accumulating function around the wrong way. They are the other way around in javascript `reduce`.

Comment: Just one question, if i wanted to use an object instead of an dictionary, could i achieve that with ur code ? Because i need to send the response back as json and it isn't working right now